# Would 64-bit DVD burning software be much faster at transcoding files on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, nero, dvd-burning

I'm currently running Nero DVD buring software that I had on my old 32 bit machine. I wonder if it would make much of a difference in terms of speed if I upgraded this software to 64 bit?

**update:** I should note that by faster, I mean the conversion from the video file (i.e. .mpeg), to the iso, which is then burnt onto the disk. I understand the DVD burner itself will always be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible the 64bit software will transcode faster by utilizing all your processors (if you have them) Older 32bit Nero software was not multiprocessor aware.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it.

64-bit has the biggest effect on *performance* in applications that perform a lot of calculations on large values (e.g. encryption or compression).

Writing a DVD is limited entirely by the speed of DVD writer.

Comment: The encoding of video and audio files might perform better though...

Comment: For some reason I always think "data" regarding burning to disk, but that's a very good point. The hardware is still going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific, thanks

Comment: @DMA57361 True...

Comment: @Dave - so really you want to ask about 64-bit video conversion software being faster or not? If so, you may wish to adjust your headline question and tags.

Comment: @DMA57361, Maybe so, but from my point of view Nero does that for me so I'm wondering specifically about that.

Comment: @Dave Fair enough, well unfortunately in this case I don't have much else of an answer for you other than "maybe"...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the bottleneck here is your writer, so I do not think that there will be a considerable performance increase. You may have better compatibility if you use 64bit version of software. Sometimes burning programs come with optimized versions of some .dll files used by windows during burning process. If you use 64bit program on 64bit version of windows, I think that it will work better but not necessarily faster, because it will be able to use .dll files shipped with it.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific, thanks

Comment: @DaveDev Interesting update. I haven't used Nero in quite a while so I don't know if 64bit version will be faster when it comes to making image.